# give column a name, name already specified in another df/list using loop

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this

```
    sl.no = c(1,2,3,4)
    vehicle = c('car, bike','car, bicycle, lorry', 'bike, lorry, bicycle', 'bike, bicycle')
    df = cbind(sl.no, vehicle)

    df

    sl.no       vehicle
    ------------------------------
     1      'car, bike'
    ------------------------------
     2      'car, bicycle, lorry'
    ------------------------------
     3      'bike, lorry, bicycle'
    ------------------------------
     4      'bike, bicycle'
    ------------------------------
```

I have created a table 'veh' contains unique vehicles. looks like this

```
    veh

     unique vehicle's
     ---------------
      car
     ---------------
      bike
     ---------------
      bicycle
     ---------------
      lorry
     ---------------
```

using both of the above table's I have created 'df1' looks like this

```
    df1

     sl.no      car     bike    bicycle     lorry
     1          1       1       0           0
     2          1       0       1           1
     3          0       1       1           1
     4          0       1       1           0
```

I can do above by using this

```
     df1$car = str_count(df$vehicle, "\\bcar\\b")
     df1$bike = str_count(df$vehicle, "\\bbike\\b")
     df1$bicycle = str_count(df$vehicle, "\\bbicycle\\b")
     df1$lorry = str_count(df$vehicle, "\\blorry\\b")
```

say, if there is new vehicle 'tractor' then again i have to write as below

```
    df1$tractor = str_count(df$vehicle, "\\btractor\\b")
```

this one creates a column of 'veh' with veh[[1]]: car

```
    df1$veh = str_count(df$vehicle, veh[[1]])
```

I want to loop them so that I don't have to specify column name and give tha details

so, how to loop it so that if new vehicle is added i don't need to add

```
    df1$tractor = str_count(df$vehicle, "\\btractor\\b")
```

and also that i don't have to give column name (df1$bicycle)

If the answer is already available. Please, provide me the link. thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop through the first column of 'veh' and get the `str_count`

```
cbind(slNo = seq_len(nrow(veh)), sapply(veh[[1]], str_count, string = df$vehicle))
#      slNo car bike bicycle lorry
#[1,]    1   1    1       0     0
#[2,]    2   1    0       1     1
#[3,]    3   0    1       1     1
#[4,]    4   0    1       1     0
```

#### data

```
veh <- data.frame(uniquevehicle = unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$vehicle), ", "))),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could generalize & streamline the solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

data_frame(
  sl.no = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  vehicle = c(
    'car, bike',
    'car, bicycle, lorry',
    'bike, lorry, bicycle',
    'bike, bicycle',
    'bike, car, tractor'
  )
) -> xdf

xdf
## # A tibble: 5 x 2
##   sl.no              vehicle
##   <dbl>                <chr>
## 1     1            car, bike
## 2     2  car, bicycle, lorry
## 3     3 bike, lorry, bicycle
## 4     4        bike, bicycle
## 5     5   bike, car, tractor

separate_rows(xdf, vehicle) %>%
  mutate(x=1) %>%
  spread(vehicle, x) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-sl.no), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))
## # A tibble: 5 x 6
##   sl.no bicycle  bike   car lorry tractor
##   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
## 1     1       0     1     1     0       0
## 2     2       1     0     1     1       0
## 3     3       1     1     0     1       0
## 4     4       1     1     0     0       0
## 5     5       0     1     1     0       1
```

Comment: NOTE: This needs modification (slight) if there's a chance it's not going to always be `1`.  It's hard to tell that from your question. Also, try to use `dput()` vs lovingly hand-craft data tables. It'll save you loads of time in the future.